# Validate that Web Service is authentic

Tags: identity, opensource

If I have a web service (REST API, RPC, etc) that I open source, how can I prove to the user that the service they are connecting with is indeed the same one whose source I published. I am envisioning an endpoint they could query and get some kind of hash/signature they can validate.

The problem seems that the API service could easily forge the returned token.

Comment: you need to provide more information: what environment, what is the scope of the service that you wish to prove? (ie. the functionality? the data? the installation? the runtime?) - signature schemes are there to solve this problem, but what is it that you are asserting to the user? ... *Soatok 2020* https://soatok.blog/2020/04/26/a-furrys-guide-to-digital-signature-algorithms/ will give you an indication of 'the how'

Answer (score 5):

This cannot reliably be done. There is no way to prove without a doubt that the site operator is telling the truth or not forging some value.

Even if you were able to prove that the source code is identical to that which is published, that doesn't really say much since 3rd-party or system libraries could be tampered with without affecting the application source.